# how to make the username box highlight?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, tags

Hello I have problem ...
i want to change the user name and password text box  highlight color in login form...
and when i click it ,it selected as square
but it is not square its rounded 
here is my code shows my problem....

html:

```
<div  id="username">
    <form>
        <p><span>UserName:</span>
            <input name="UserName" type="text" size="0" id="box1" >
        </p>
    </form>
</div>


<div class="login_form" id="pass">
    <form>
        <p>
            <span>Password:</span>
            <input  name="lastname" type="password" id="box2">
        </p>
    </form>
</div>
```

css:

```
    #pass {
    position: absolute;
    top: 22px;
    left: 963px;
    right: 10%;
    width: 280px;
    height: 62px;
    border-radius: 20px;
    font-family: corbel;
}

#username {
    position:absolute;
    top: 23px;
    left: 709px;
    right: 10%;
    width: 280px;
    height: 61px;
    font-family: corbel;
    border:medium;
    border-color:black;
}


#button {
    position: absolute;
    left: 1170px;
    top: 40px;
    background-color: #FFFFFF;
    font-family:corbel;
}

#loginform {
    position:absolute;
    left:100px
}

#bar{
    position:absolute;
    top:0;
    left:0;
    background-color:black;
}

#login{
    position: absolute;
    top: 42px;
    left: 1202px;
    width: 63px;
    height: 19px;
    background-color: #2799b6;
    text-align: center;
    font-family: corbel;
    border-radius:20px;
    color:#FFF;
    font-size:15px;
    opacity:1;
    -moz-transition:    opacity .5s;
    -o-transition:      opacity .5s;
    -webkit-transition: opacity .5s;
    transition:         opacity .5s;
}

#link {
    text-decoration:none
}

#login:hover {
    opacity:0.7;
    -moz-transition:    opacity .5s;
    -o-transition:      opacity .5s;
    -webkit-transition: opacity .5s;
    transition:         opacity .5s;
}

#box1 {
    border: 2px solid #bfbfbf;
    border-radius:20px;
}

#box2 {
    border: 2px solid #bfbfbf;
    border-radius:20px;
}
```

Comment: Please clarify your problem. What kind of change do you want to apply to the hightlight? its color? make the highlight round or make the border square?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think that using the CSS's `focus` property should work:

```
input:focus {
    border: 1px solid #006600;
}
```

Edit:
[DEMO [JSFIDDLE]](http://jsfiddle.net/8Y66Q/)

**Update**: To remove the default outline (which is yellow), you can set the `outline` property to `none`:

```
input {
   outline:none;
}
```

Here is the [updated fiddle.](http://jsfiddle.net/viphalongpro/8Y66Q/1/)

Comment: Thank you it worked , but there is a problem instead of the focus property it make an sqaured yellow line , and i need to remove it

Comment: @user3516809 see update. Here is the modified code (from your own): http://jsfiddle.net/viphalongpro/PyB4t/10/

Comment: I can't quite understand you, can you be more clear?

Answer (score 0):

Just add the following lines of code to your CSS and this should fix your problem:

```
input[type=text], /*transition delay*/
textarea {
 -webkit-transition: all 0.35s ease-in-out;
 -moz-transition: all 0.35s ease-in-out;
 -ms-transition: all 0.35s ease-in-out;
 -o-transition: all 0.35s ease-in-out;
 outline: none;
 padding: 3px 0px 3px 3px;
 margin: 5px 1px 3px 0px;
 border: 2px solid #f1f1f1;
}

input[type=text]:focus, /*creates highlight effect*/
textarea:focus {
  box-shadow: 0 0 3px rgba(81, 203, 238, 1);
  padding: 3px 0px 3px 3px;
  margin: 5px 1px 3px 0px;
  border: 1px solid rgba(81, 203, 238, 1);
}

input[type=password], textarea{ /*prevents showing outline border when clicked*/
 outline: 0;
}
```